# Mapping A Keras Model Prediction over a tf Dataset such that order is maintained

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I have a tensorflow dataset such that each iteration of the dataset returns a tuple of the following form:

`(data features, data label, file_name, some other attributes)`

I am using a standard VG19 pretrained model from keras and I would like to get a dataset out from this in the following way:

`(data features, transformed data features, data label, file name, some other attributes)`

I don't want to loose the association with the other files.

Here is some sample code I am running that is not working and may illustrate my point:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

# Create a dataset with tuples like the following: (x, 2*x, 3*x)
datasetx = tf.data.Dataset.range(100)
datasety = tf.data.Dataset.range(100).map(lambda x: x*2)
datasetz = tf.data.Dataset.range(100).map(lambda x: x*3)
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((datasetx, datasety, datasetz)).shuffle(10)

# Create a simple (dumb) model
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.relu),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=None)
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='mse',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train the model
model.fit(dataset.map(lambda x, y, z: (tf.reshape(x, [1,1]), y)),
          steps_per_epoch=1)

# Map the prediction over the dataset
predicted_tuples = dataset.map(lambda x, y, z: (model.predict(x, steps=1), y, z))
iterator = predicted_tuples.make_one_shot_iterator()
next_element = iterator.get_next()
with tf.Session() as sess:
  print(list(sess.run(next_element) for i in range(100)))
```

This does not work at the moment.

I would also be fine with something like this, but order is not maintained in this case:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

# Create a dataset with tuples like the following: (x, 2*x, 3*x)
datasetx = tf.data.Dataset.range(100)
datasety = tf.data.Dataset.range(100).map(lambda x: x*2)
datasetz = tf.data.Dataset.range(100).map(lambda x: x*3)
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((datasetx, datasety, datasetz)).shuffle(10)

# Create a simple (dumb) model
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.relu),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=None)
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='mse',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train the model
model.fit(dataset.map(lambda x, y, z: (tf.reshape(x, [1,1]), y)),
          steps_per_epoch=1)

# Map the prediction over the dataset
X = model.predict(dataset.map(lambda x, y, z: tf.reshape(x, [1,1])), steps=100)
Y = dataset.map(lambda x, y, z: y)
Z = dataset.map(lambda x, y, z: z)

it_Y = Y.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
it_Z = Z.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
with tf.Session() as sess:
  print(zip(X, list(sess.run(it_Y, it_Z) for i in range(100))))
```

I need something like this, but not something exactly like this, as long as the tuple data can be maintained and guarenteed. I also need it to run fast and parallelized. Anyone have any idea what I need?

Comment: Did you figure out a solution to your problem?